# PowerApps attachment control how to check if any attachments have been made

Tags: attachment, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I am in the process of building a PowerApp that stores its data on a SharePoint OnLine list.

One of the fields is meant to be an Attachments Control that may carry one or more files.  The record is validated by checking for data in relevant fields; I need to check whether or not the Attachments Control has any items attached to it.

I was unable to find out how to see if the Attachments Control has some property that would at least tell me if there are attachments associated with the control.  The Microsoft documentation doesn't seem to describe any such feature, is there something I missed?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
If(
     CountRows(Your_Attachment_Control.Attachments) < 1,
     Notify("Please add an attachment", Error),
     SubmitForm(Your_Form_Name)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using the "OnAddFile" property for the attachments control.

Here are the steps I took:

1) on your attachment control, set the property "OnAddFile" to "Set(IsAttached, true)"
*IsAttached can be any name you want, this is just the variable name you decide*

2) set the property "OnRemoveFile" to "Set(IsAttached, false)". This will ensure the variable is set back to false if the attachment is removed.

3) In my case I'm using a sumbit button, and I have it disabled until an attachment is added - if you're interested in doing this create a button and change it's "DisplayMode" property to "If(IsAttached = true, DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)"

Hope this helps